# What is the stick shift called in an automatic?

Tags: terminology

In a manual transmission car, the transmission control is generally called the "stick shift". What is it called in an automatic car?

Comment: "stick shift" refers to a car with manual transmission, not to the transmission control. "My car is a stick shift"

Comment: I always called it a prndl (prounced prenundle), park, reverse,neutral,drive,low....yes I am old.

Answer (score 4):

Both are just called either the gear lever or shift lever (in the UK anyway) Auto or manual then just refers to the transmission type.

Comment: I've also seen 'gear selector' used for automatics.

Comment: Shift lever=Automatic here in the USA across the pond.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the Midwest region in USA, I've heard "gearshift" and "gear selector" used for both manual and automatic, "shift lever" for an automatic with a stick, or "shift knob" for a dial-type selector.

Answer (score 0):

Gear knob, shift knob. Depends on the shape. But the UK defined terminology is correct. In USA it's just  referred as gear knob.

Comment: That's just the knob on the end of the lever.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a gear shift lever or gear selector. Some call it simply a shifter.

According to the 2014 Dodge Ram owner's manual, it has the following;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answers, it is called the gear lever, selector, knob, etc...

If you are trying to find the name of the manual shifting in automatic, then the portmanteau term is "Manumatic". However, I have mostly heard it as TipTronic, S-Tronic, E-Shift and SportShift trademarks from different manufacturers.